# How to know how much of an aborted POST request was sent?

Tags: javascript, upload, fetch-api

I want to send a POST request with a huge body to a server, then abort it after a specified period so I could measure the uplink bandwidth. I know that [cloudflare's speedtest website](https://speed.cloudflare.com/) accepts such requests. The api looks like this: to send a 1MB file one can simply use this snippet.

```
let size = 1 * 1e6; // 1MB
let url = `https://speed.cloudflare.com/__up`;
let req =  await fetch(`${url}`, {...{
  method: 'POST',
  body: '0'.repeat(size),
  headers: { 'content-length': size }
}});
let res = await req.text();
console.log(res);
```

Copy pasting the snippet above in a chrome console sends out a successful `1MB` request for me.

What I'm trying to do is to `abort` this request using the [Abort Controller API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController), then have some form of measurement over how much of the body of the request was sent to the server.

For download I can do that as I use the [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams) on the download request so I know how much of the file was downloaded before I cancelled the download.

Is this possible?

Comment: I was tempted to go down the path of using a `ReadableStream` for the `body` of the options, but all that would tell you is how much the browser's `fetch` implementation *read* from the stream, not how much was actually sent to the other end; those could be **very** different numbers...

Comment: *"For download I can do that as I use the `ReadableStream` on the download request so I know how much of the file was downloaded before I cancelled the download."* I'm not at all sure you can rely on that, for the same reason I couldn't for the upload test. You'll know how much you read from the stream, not how much the browser read from the other end and buffered... But I think for download you're much more likely to be able to tell, if you get your code right (basically, keep reading even past the point you've aborted -- if it lets you? -- to exhaust any browser buffer involved).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder good point! I'm comparing my bandwidth calculations with speedtest.net and they seem to be very close to each other. I'm guessing for a download of 100MB if the unflushed buffer size is around a couple hunderd kilobytes (or even megabytes) the error is pretty low (almost in the same order of magnitude of my bandwidth fluctuations from my ISP.) I'm hoping for upload something similar happens.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Currently, I'm trying using `ReadableStream` as the body but looks like the server instantly replies with a status ok even before getting all of my data, so I'm a little confused by that.